# Portlet Data sharing using liferay and icefaces

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, sharing, icefaces

I am using liferay 1.8.2 and liferay 5.2. I have many portlets in different war files and I tried the examples in the liferay docs as to how to share data between differenet portlets across multiple wars with no success.

1. With sesssion sharing , I was not able to get the data from the first portlet to the second portlet, even thou the data was in the portletsession application scope.
2. When I use the even based mechanism, I get an error when I use the 
   `<portlet:defineObjects /> and <portlet:actionURL />` tags

> Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Failed to execute JSP lifecycle.
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:181)
>       at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:439)
>       ... 189 more
>    Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at com.liferay.taglib.portlet.ActionURLTag.doEndTag(ActionURLTag.java:212)
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:246)
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.executeJspLifecycle(Parser.java:229)
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:162)
>       ... 190 more
>    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:180)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:49)
>       at com.liferay.taglib.portlet.ActionURLTag.doTag(ActionURLTag.java:179)
>       at com.liferay.taglib.portlet.ActionURLTag.doEndTag(ActionURLTag.java:200) 
>       ... 199 more
>    Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.taglib.portlet.ActionURLTagUtil.doEndTag(ActionURLTagUtil.java:174)
>       ... 207 more
>    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>       at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.StubHttpServletRequest.getAttribute(StubHttpServletRequest.java:116)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.taglib.portlet.TagUtil.getPortletName(TagUtil.java:100)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.taglib.portlet.ActionURLTagUtil.doEndTag(ActionURLTagUtil.java:68)

Can anybody suggest with detailed explaination and sample code, how I can achieve IPC between portlets residing across different WAR

Comment: Why post silly questions here when you don't need an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Inter Portlet Commuication (IPC) is not possible across different WARs using IceFaces 1.8.x.

It will be possible when IceFaces 2.0 is out, an Alpha is already available.

However, it is possible to do some sort of IPC using IceFaces 1.8.x. The "Advanced Topics" chapter of the Icefaces Develpers Guide covers this topic:

> The use of Ajax Push allows portlets
>   to be updated based on server-side
>   events that change the state of the
>   current view. This can be a powerful
>   feature that can also be leveraged to
>   do a form of interportlet
>   communication (IPC) in certain
>   configurations.
>
> IPC is only mentioned in the Portlet
>   1.0 spec (JSR 168) but is formally defined in the Portlet 2.0
>   specification (JSR 286).
>
> It is architected as an Event/Listener
>   model. However, it is possible to use
>   the ICEfaces Ajax Push mechanism to
>   update portlets based on changes to
>   the underlying model. The way to do
>   this currently with ICEfaces is to:
>
> - Deploy the portlets that need to    communicate in the same archive (.war 
>     file).
> - Use application-scoped beans    to manage shared state between the
>     portlets.
> - Use the ICEfaces Ajax Push    feature to trigger client updates
>     when the shared state changes.
> - For an    example of how to do this, review the    sample ICEfaces Chat
>     portlet.